# Winston logs does not work in the Docker Container

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, express, winston

I am creating a nodejs/express app with typescript. I have installed the winston package. using `npm install winston`.
I am following this [article](https://dev.to/vassalloandrea/better-logs-for-expressjs-using-winston-and-morgan-with-typescript-516n).  i want to dockerize this.

What i have done so far:

1. I have imported the winston package in the logger.ts.
2. import the logger.js file to the server.ts file.

Winston logger works when I run `npm run dev` command. I see the winston logs in the console.
When i implement the same in docker container.

I use `docker build -t docker-image .` command then `docker-compose up`.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# Bundle app source
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "node", "dist/server.js" ]
```

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: hoptik-pims-node
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '2717:27017'
```

I try to access the page http://localhost:5000/logger. I get Cannot GET /logger.
[image]
I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I have spent last couple of days trying fix this issue. Can someone help me fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are doing it wrong, in order to view logs you should not be going to localhost:5000/logger, instead you should be looking at docker logs using following command

```
docker logs <your-container-id> -f
```

Example looks like

```
docker logs 2921e28c845f -f
```

OR

```
docker logs 2921e28c845f5ba9c97c371b81e1d68db28650e576ea18b78592713362baa140 -f
```

This should show you proper logs.